# How to run automated test cases in TFS 2015 web?

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, automation, automated-tests, mstest

I have test cases in TFS 2015. How to run automated tests using TFS 2015 web (similar to Microsoft Test Manager)? Basically I would like to know how to achieve automated testing in TFS 2015 web platform without using MTM?

Answer (score 2):

The web Test page does not support to run automatic tests associated with test cases. You can achieve the same goals using the Build & Release features in Team Foundation Server (TFS). (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/lab-management/use-build-or-rm-instead-of-lab-management)

Use the [Visual Studio Test Agent Deploy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/visual-studio-test-agent-deployment) and [Run Functional tests](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/run-functional-tests) steps in your build definition to run auto tests on build agents.

1. Associated test methods with test cases in Visual Studio.
2. Create a build definition to build your project and add the 2 steps I mentioned above. In the Run Functional Test step, select the test suits which contains those test cases in step1.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't. You either integrate testing into a continuous integration/continuous delivery pipeline with the "Run Functional Tests" task (which, frankly, is where it belongs), or you continue to use MTM.

Comment: How to integrate testing into a continuous integration/continuous delivery pipeline with the "Run Functional Tests" task? Any links or tutorials to follow?

Comment: @meshsf: Not sure if you found what you're looking for, but here's a useful link: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/run-functional-tests